# Solution wide PostSharp configuration not working

Tags: postsharp

We decided to get PostSharp Ultimate at work to help me diagnose some deadlock situations. Currently waiting on the licenses so I'm playing around with the trial period version.

I've followed the instructions at [Detecting Deadlocks at Runtime](https://doc.postsharp.net/deadlock-detection). I'm using VS 2017 Enterprise 15.9.20 with PostSharp 6.4.7. Ideally I'd set this up at the solution level. I've tried both adding the policy with PostSharp Tools as well as adding manually. Neither seemed to work. However, manually adding it to the project did work.

I suspected that it wasn't reading the pssln file, so I edited it to be invalid xml. No change. Decided to try in release mode and then it started complaining. Reverted the pssln back to the valid config and ran in release and then it worked.

So, I guess the issue is that pssln files only work for release builds. Why wouldn't a pssln file be picked up in a debug build?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to reproduce this behavior. It is a bug in PostSharp and it will be fixed in future versions.

As a work-around, you can rename the .pssln file to `postsharp.config`. PostSharp searches all directories from the project location up to the root looking for `postsharp.config` files and loads each on the way. So if you place the file next to your solution file, you'd get a solution-wide configuration this way, unless some of your project is located outside of the solution directory.

Docs: https://doc.postsharp.net/configuration-system

Comment: This solution seems to have the same problem. Only works in Release and not in Debug.

Comment: I was going to go ahead and try just using Release mode, but the solution level menu item to add a PostSharp Policy is missing. Oddly enough, a newly created solution has the menu item, so I guess there's something odd about my existing solution. I guess I can add it manually to each project, but would prefer not to have to do that.

Comment: So, somehow I got postsharp.config to work in Debug. I think it may have been due to closing the solution and reopening.